# DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner (DQN) can not run game roms other than breakout

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, torch, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am studying https://github.com/kuz/DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner these days. I successfully trained breakout on my machine. However, when I tried to run the games downloaded from http://www.atariage.com/, they all failed by both run_cpu and run_gpu. I have already replaced the capitalized letters for the game bin files.

Here are some game roms downloaded from http://www.atariage.com/system_items.html?SystemID=2600&ItemTypeID=ROM and only breakout works.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~/Github/DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner/roms$ ls
breakout.bin  mspacman.bin  rsboxing.bin  vidpin.bin
montzrev.bin  README        spcinvad.bin
```

All other games failed because of this error:
[image]

```
./run_cpu: line 46: 17785 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ../torch/bin/qlua train_agent.lua $args
```

Given that I am using a server which has a 512GB RAM and 8 GPUs of Nvidia Titan X, the hardware should not be a problem. I wonder how to fix this issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Perhaps it is due to the names of the bin files not being consistent with ALE naming? When I rename the file to pacman.bin it runs. All others seg fault for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

ALE relies on the ROM filename to determine how to handle the ROM. Make sure your ROM filename matches that which ALE requires: [list](http://yavar.naddaf.name/ale/list_of_current_games.html).

So, for example, if you are running the space invaders ROM, your file should be called space_invaders.bin, in accordance with the list I have linked to. Have fun!